# List the numbers in order

Tags: exponentiation

How would I list these numbers in order without using a calculator? 
Thank you

> List these numbers in increasing order: $2^{800}$, $3^{600}$, $5^{400}$, $6^{200}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$2^{800} = 16^{200}$$ $$3^{600} = 27^{200}$$ $$5^{400} = 25^{200}$$

so the order is: $6^{200}, 2^{800}, 5^{400}, 3^{600}$.

Comment: Excellent thank you this was method I couldnt remember!!

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to compare among

$$2^4=16,3^3=27,5^2=25,6^1=6$$

as for positive real numbers $a,b>1$  and $n>0$ if $a>b\implies a^n>b^n$

here $n=200$